# PyCharm debug mode throws fake errors but runs normally when not in debug

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

**EDIT**: I rolled back PyCharm versions and it's working again. CLEARLY an IDE issue, not a script issue now. PyCharm version 2017.2.4 is what I rolled back to.

So I have a script that's been working great for me, until today. For some reason, the script will run fine with no errors at all, as long as I don't use PyCharm (Community Edition 2017.3.3) in debugging mode. I need to use debugger, so when it throws errors for no reason and stops the script, it makes it a pointless IDE.

The reason I know this is a PyCharm problem is because I copied the entire script into a different IDE (Wing), set to the same python interpreter, and went through it in debug mode there and it worked fine, no errors.

I have done extensive error testing to make sure the errors aren't actually there in my script; they're not. The script should work as written. It keeps saying datasets don't exist or input features for arcpy tools (a spatial program that hooks into python via a library called "arcpy") don't have values when they do. It's not a script problem, it's an IDE problem.

Has anybody encountered this and know how to fix it?

I do not have any specific environment settings, I just popped an ArcGIS python interpreter in there for the project so I could have access to the arcpy library and that's it. It should be noted that this interpreter is python 2.7 because ArcGIS is not yet compatible with python 3+. I doubt that has anything to do with it, but you never know...

This is a chunk of script causing the issues (if you don't have/know how to use ArcGIS don't bother trying to run it, it won't work for you). What I want to point out is that if I put a breakpoint at the `qh_buffer` line, it will break after trying to run that line with an arcpy error message that states invalid input/parameters (they are not invalid, it's written exactly how it should be and I have checked that `qhPolys` is being created and exists). THEN, if I move the breakpoint to the `crop_intersect` line and run it in debug, it runs through the entire code, INCLUDING the buffer statement, but then errors out with error 000732 "Input Features: Dataset #1; #2 does not exist or is not supported" (they both do exist, because I have hardcoded them to an output directory before and they are created just fine).

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

svyPtFC = r"C:\Users\xxx\GIS_Testing\Crop_Test.shp"

select_query = '"FID" = 9'

qhPolys = arcpy.Select_analysis(svyPtFC, 'in_memory/qhPolys', select_query)
qh_buffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(qhPolys, 'in_memory/qh_buffer', '50 
Meters')
cropFID = '"FID" = 1'
cropPoly = arcpy.Select_analysis(svyPtFC, 'in_memory/cropPoly', cropFID)
crop_intersect = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([[cropPoly, 1], [qh_buffer, 2]],
                                      r'C:\Users\xxx\GIS_Testing\crp_int.shp')
feature_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(crop_intersect)
print feature_count
```

It does not make sense that it can cause an error at the buffer line if I put a breakpoint near there, but then if I move the breakpoint further down, that line will run fine and it'll just break at the next breakpoint... does explain why it works when you just hit "Run" instead of doing debug mode though. No breakpoints!

Comment: The most important thing is missing: the errors and their stacktraces.

Comment: @CristiFati - They are not PyCharm errors. If you do not work with ArcPy you will not understand the errors so they're a bit irrelevant to my post, but I understand why you asked for them. They are errors sent by the software program because an arcpy tool failed. For instance, one of them is "Error 000732: Input Features: Dataset #1; #2 does not exist or is not supported" (they do exist and they are supported). Despite the errors being ArcPy errors, it is a problem with the IDE because I can run this script elsewhere and it works as expected. I can even run it in PyCharm if not in debug mode.

Comment: Hmm,  it might have smth to do with the way that *Pycharm* calls its debugger (*pydevd.py*) which might conflict with the other tool. Try running it with/without debug get the 1st lines from the *Pycharm* console (that is the cmdline) and do some comparisons.

Comment: @CristiFati - Possibly, though aside from the pyded.py being called with some extra flags (--multiproc --qt-support = auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 5727) I'm not seeing much difference. The problem seems to stem from the breakpoints; it runs successfully in "Run" mode and "Debug" mode as long as when in debug mode there are zero breakpoints (which kinda defeats the purpose of debug).

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/268973/115

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - thanks for your question, please read one of my previous comments to CristiFati on why the errors are not helpful for you guys. The last portion of my original post also explains the errors. Long story short, they are not PyCharm error messages, they are related to the python library I am using. Does not matter though as I have proven it is a PyCharm IDE problem, not a library/script problem by rolling back versions of PyCharm and being able to run my script in debug successfully.

Comment: I question your conclusion that the errors do not matter. It appears that you are correct that the problem is with PyCharm and not the library which throws the errors. More correctly, the problem appears to be with how the PyCharm debugger interacts with said library. This indicates that the errors can give some clues to why PyCharm is misbehaving.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Have any ideas on what the issue could be with the debugger? Have you seen this happen with other python libraries? I'm open to suggestions because I have zero clue.

Answer (score 0):

disabling cython speedups by adding `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` environment variable to the run/debug configuration helped in my case (as suggested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-59698/Exception-only-happens-in-PyCharms-debug-mode))