# My code will not print

Tags: java, object, constructor, println

I am brand new to computer programming, and the project that I was assigned is very confusing to me. The code I've written so far has no errors , yet it will not print.

This is the project:

Classes and Objects Program

1. Create a Employee Object with methods and instance fields (State variables)
2. Constructor takes a Strings, an int and a double (name, social security number and hourly wage)
3. Convert the int into a String with the format 123-45-6789
4. Hire five new employees (5 objects)
5. Create a scanner
6. Create a loop the enter the following data for each object

   a.  SS# or name

   b. hour worked

   c. at least one employee worked more than 40 hours
7. Print a payroll report of the employees

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
package Employee;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


/**
  * Write a description of class Employee here.*
  *  @author (your name)
  *  @version (a version number or a date)
  */

public class Employee{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String NAME = scanner.nextLine();
        int hrs = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    /**
      *  Constructor for objects of class Employee
      */
    public Employee(String name, int employeenumber, double hourlypay)
    {
        socialsecurity = employeenumber;
        employeename= name;
        rate= hourlypay;
        TaxRate =.2;
    }

    public String SSN() {
        return  String.format("Social Security Number: ",
            (int) socialsecurity / 1000000,
            (int)(socialsecurity % 1000000) / 10000, 
            socialsecurity % 10000);

            //return " ";
    }

    public double paycheck(double h)//pay
    {
        return paycheck;
    }

    private int socialsecurity;
    public String employeename;
    private double rate;
    public double paycheck;
    public double TaxRate;

}

/**
  *  Company X payroll program**  Vincent Wrencher
  *  the Dark Side provided assistance**  1/24/2018
  */
class Tester
{
    public static void main (String arg[])
    {
        double hours;
        int hoursworked = 1;
        String printout = " Name /t /t /t/t SS# /t /t Pay /n -----------------------------/n";

        Employee e1 = new Employee(" Kat",100805600, 10.50);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hours Worked: " +  e1.employeename);

        Employee e2 = new Employee("Genesis", 123-456789, 11);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hours Worked: " +  e2.employeename);

        Employee e3 = new Employee("Falcore", 987654321, 11);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hours Worked: " +  e3.employeename);

        Employee e4 = new Employee("Alexandria", 132435465, 11);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hours Worked: " +  e4.employeename);

        Employee e5 = new Employee("Evangeline", 543264397, 11);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hours Worked: " +  e5.employeename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running Tester.main() and not Employee.main()?

Comment: As you start your journey into the wonderful world of programming, you need to learn how to debug code. You will spend just as much of your time debugging as you do writing code to begin with. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410264/pycharm-debug-mode-throws-fake-errors-but-runs-normally-when-not-in-debug and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Not all errors are caught by the compiler. Only the simplest ones in fact are.

Comment: Tester main works fine in my local.

Answer (score 0):

You have public main() method in Employee class (which is a public class). This method gets executed and not the one in your Tester class. You may remove main() from Employee class and it will work. And as it can be seen, the main() in Employee class does not print anything.

Comment: I tried removing the public main() method from the Employee class but now it is saying      Error: Main method not found in class Employee.Employee, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Remove main from Employee. You should not have Employee class as public. Make Tester class public and have main() in `public class Tester`